# How do I network a real Android device with an Emulator?

Tags: android

What if I want to connect my Android mobile with my PC server so that my mobile can send my data (my current location) to my PC? The socket between my mobile Android and my PC (SERVER) doesn't work. Any suggestions? It only works when using the android emulator.

Comment: That is a unique feature of the emulator.  You will need to use one of the workarounds proposed below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step #1: Connect the phone to a local network via WiFi.

Step #2: Connect the PC to the same network.

Step #3: Write an app server on the PC that is listening on an IP address on that network (hint: not just `localhost`).

Comment: @eoeo: The port number the PC listens on can be any 'free' port number, in other words any port which isn't being used by any other application on the PC. Try 6789 or 9876 or 8899 etc etc. As long as the phone uses the same number, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative using USB if you don't want to rely on your local network:

1. configure Tethering & portable hotspot on Android
2. connect the computer to the hotspot using USB
3. start the PC (SERVER)
4. connect the Android client

Answer (score 0):

You should connect to IP of your PC at any free port. Port should match the one server listens on.

You can get this IP from ipconfig or ifconfig or something else (depends on OS you have).

If your PC is under NAT (doesn't have "white" IP-address, but have non-world IP, such as 192.168.whatever, 10.10.whatever) you should additionally configure network and connect to appropriate port.

You write "socket doesn't work". Can you give more info? What does your server log say? No incoming connection at all?